# Unable to run serverspec due to gem being unable to load

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rake

I'm trying to play around with serverspec, however it seems I have some weird gem error that I cannot pinpoint.

```
 $ rake spec
/usr/bin/ruby -I/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-support-3.0.2/lib:/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/lib -S /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/exe/rspec spec/localhost/httpd_spec.rb
/home/mikolajewskim/puppet-master/spec/spec_helper.rb:1:in `require': no such file to load -- serverspec (LoadError)
        from /home/mikolajewskim/puppet-master/spec/spec_helper.rb:1
        from /home/mikolajewskim/puppet-master/spec/localhost/httpd_spec.rb:1:in `require'
        from /home/mikolajewskim/puppet-master/spec/localhost/httpd_spec.rb:1
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1057:in `load'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1057:in `load_spec_files'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1057:in `each'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1057:in `load_spec_files'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:97:in `setup'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:85:in `run'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:70:in `run'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:38:in `invoke'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/exe/rspec:4
/usr/bin/ruby -I/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-support-3.0.2/lib:/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/lib -S /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2/exe/rspec spec/localhost/httpd_spec.rb failed
```

Still, when I look at the list of gems, serverspec is there (1.9.0). I've also checked it's existance in gems directory. I'm running a system version of ruby 1.8.7 and I do not have multiple ruby installations.

I'm not really sure where to go from here. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: are you using `bundler`? Try `bundle exec rake spec`

Comment: No, I don't have bundler.

Answer (score 0):

What helped was:
1) Upgrading ruby package on the system (still 1.8.7).
2) Upgrading rubygems.
3) Removing all gems.
4) Installing serverspec and rake again.